# In django mapping how to get complete count of choice filed

Tags: python, django

I want the Count of my (Booking Type) I have 3 types of choices (choice field in Model) Individual, Group, and Certificate.

```
d1 = Booking.objects.values('booking_type').annotate(booking_count=Count('booking_type'))
{f.get('booking_type'): f.get('booking_count') for f in d1}
```

Below is the output of the above: However Why does the code not give me the Count of Certificate

`{'GROUP': 2, 'INDIVIDUAL': 3}`

I changed the values to filter too, however nothing works.

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: Where is the Certificate Count

Answer (score 1):

> But why the code Will Cant give me the Count of Certificate.

Because that count is zero, and since a database works under the *closed world assumption*. It thus does not know these values exists.

You probably need to add a `.order_by(..)` to force Django to perform a `GROUP BY`. Furthermore we can use the `choices` to add zeros to these items:

```
d1 = Booking.objects.values('booking_type').annotate(
    booking_count=Count('booking_type')
).order_by('booking_type')
result = {f['booking_type']: f['booking_count'] for f in d1}

for c in Booking._meta.get_field('booking_type').choices:
    result.setdefault(c[0], 0)
```

Comment: You will need to add `from django.db.models import Count`